# how to get computed column value in stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008

I am using ASP.NET 4.0, C# and SQL Server 2008 R2. I am getting `UserName` from the user in a webpage for stored in the SQL table `User_Info2`. Using SQL Server 2008 feature "computed column" I am generating the `Vendor_ID` automatically for every `Insert` using the stored procedure. In button click, after I insert the record I want to display the message with `Vendor_ID`, so please anyone tell me how to get the `Vendor_ID` column from the stored procedure ?

```
    CREATE TABLE User_Info2
    (  SNo int Identity (2000,1) , 
       Vendor_ID AS 'VEN' + CAST(SNo as varchar(16)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY, 
       UserName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    )
```

Stored procedure

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_User_Info2] @UserName VARCHAR(30)
    AS  
    BEGIN 
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       INSERT INTO User_Info2 (UserName) VALUES (@UserName)   
    END
```

C# Code :

```
protected void BtnUserNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{      
  SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());  
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();   
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
  cmd.CommandText = "usp_User_Info2";   
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUserName.Text.Trim();      
  cmd.Connection = SqlCon;    
  try   
  {     
     SqlCon.Open();   
     cmd.ExecuteScalar();  
  }  
  finally   
  {
    string url = "../CompanyBasicInfo.aspx?Parameter=" + Server.UrlEncode ("+ Vendor_ID  +");
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"callfunction",
    "alert('Login created  successfully for "+ Vendor_ID +"');
    window.location.href = '"  + url + "';", true); 
    SqlCon.Close();    
  }    
}
```

Comment: do you want to get inserted id value??

Comment: use  Select query for last record

Comment: I have to declare the Vendor_ID in SP like this ? @Vendor_ID INT OUTPUT ?

Answer (score 6):

You can output the inserted value using the `OUTPUT` clause, and then read it when you execute the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_User_Info2] @UserName VARCHAR(30)
AS  
BEGIN 
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO User_Info2 (UserName) 
   OUTPUT Inserted.Vendor_ID
   VALUES (@UserName)   
END
```

and in your C# calling code:

```
  object spResult;
  string vendorID;

  try   
  {     
     SqlCon.Open();   
     spResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar();  

     if(spResult != null)  // check to make sure you got something back!
     {
         vendorID = spResult.ToString();
     }        
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_User_Info2] @UserName VARCHAR(30)
AS  
BEGIN 
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   declare @Id int

   INSERT INTO User_Info2 (UserName) VALUES (@UserName)   

   SET @Id = Scope_Identity()

   SELECT Vendor_ID From User_Info2 WHERE SNo = @Id
END
```

C#

```
try   
{     
  SqlCon.Open();   
  string VendorID = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;  
}
```

Comment: Now i get differ problem.Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137760/how-to-get-computed-column-value-in-stored-procedure

Comment: what do you mean? You can ask a new question

Comment: Yes.Problem to pass the parameter to the computed column Vendor_ID.I am not able to find the solution for the Error "Procedure or function usp_User_Info3 has too many arguments specified".So i asked a new Question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156132/stored-procedure-error-when-use-computed-column-for-id

Comment: No.I try many times for past 2 days with differ codes and change in SP but same error repeat "too many arguments".Please help

Answer (score 0):

Also u can do like this

```
select top(1) Vendor_ID from User_Info2 order by SNo desc
```

Comment: This just returns any "top 1" row - but not necessarily the one inserted.... what if multiple clients have inserted multiple rows more or less at the same time?? You just get back the last - but it might not be the one that this call has inserted.....

Comment: execute this query only after insertion,so it display the last insertion record

Comment: I understand your approach - but in a system under load, this is **not** reliable - not at all. .... if you have 50 clients pounding at the database - there's **no guarantee** that you'll get back the row that you've actually inserted. You should **at least** also make sure to select the correct rows: `WHERE UserName = @UserName` - but even that isn't 100% safe and reliable.

Comment: If at the same time multiple records are inserted then it will only return last inserted value..so it's not reliable..

Comment: @marc_s: Sir i agree with you, your answer is better in all perspective, just for curiosity if i add it to stordprocedure and return value then also ders chances to get wrong record ??

Comment: No - because the `OUTPUT` clause will return exactly that one value that you've inserted - it doesn't go back to the table (that might have been changed by other clients in the meantime) - it always returns exactly that value that your own `INSERT` statement has inserted into the table - nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You can get currently insert row with the help of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

```
SET @SNo = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

And below insert query you can execute select query on the `@SNo`

So it would be:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_User_Info2] 
(
    @UserName VARCHAR(30),
    @SNo int,
    @Vendor_ID VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
)
AS  
BEGIN 
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO User_Info2 (UserName) VALUES (@UserName)
   SET @SNo = Scope_Identity()


   select @Vendor_ID as Vendor_ID from User_Info2 where SNo = @SNo

END
```

**EDIT:**

```
SqlParameter[] param= new SqlParameter[1];

param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Vendor_ID", 0);
param[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

//  Here there will be a Stored Procedure Call

int VendorID = Convert.ToInt32(param[0].Value);
```

So now you will `@Vendor_ID` which is an `Output` variable.

Comment: Please refer this and reply. Thanks in advance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137760/how-to-get-computed-column-value-in-stored-procedure