# Stored procedure error when use computed column for ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I got the error:

> Procedure or function usp_User_Info3 has too many arguments specified

When I run the program. I don't know the error in SP or in C# code. I have to display the `Vendor_ID` after the user clicks the submit button. Where the thing going wrong here ?

Table structure :

```
         CREATE TABLE User_Info3 
         ( 
         SNo int Identity (2000,1) ,  
         Vendor_ID AS 'VEN' + CAST(SNo as varchar(16)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY, 
         UserName VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
         User_Password VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL, 
         User_ConPassword VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL, 
         User_FirstName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
         User_LastName VARCHAR(25) SPARSE NULL, 
         User_Title VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL, 
         User_EMail VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL, 
         User_PhoneNo VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL, 
         User_MobileNo VARCHAR(14)NOT NULL, 
         User_FaxNo VARCHAR(14)NOT NULL, 
         UserReg_Date DATE DEFAULT GETDATE() 
         )
```

Stored Procedure :

```
         ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_User_Info3]
         @SNo INT OUTPUT,
         @Vendor_ID VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT, 
         @UserName VARCHAR(30),
         @User_Password VARCHAR(12),
         @User_ConPassword VARCHAR(12),
         @User_FirstName VARCHAR(25),
         @User_LastName VARCHAR(25),
         @User_Title VARCHAR(35),
         @User_OtherEmail VARCHAR(30),
         @User_PhoneNo VARCHAR(14),
         @User_MobileNo VARCHAR(14),
         @User_FaxNo VARCHAR(14)
         AS
         BEGIN
          SET NOCOUNT ON;
         INSERT INTO User_Info3 (UserName,User_Password,User_ConPassword,User_FirstName,     
         User_LastName,User_Title,User_OtherEmail,User_PhoneNo,User_MobileNo,User_FaxNo)
               VALUES  (@UserName,@User_Password,@User_ConPassword,@User_FirstName,@User_LastName,
               @User_Title,@User_OtherEmail,@User_PhoneNo,@User_MobileNo,@User_FaxNo)
        SET @SNo = Scope_Identity()
        SELECT Vendor_ID From User_Info3 WHERE SNo = @SNo
        END
```

C# Code :

```
         protected void BtnUserNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.CommandText = "usp_User_Info3";
         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter SNo=cmd.Parameters.Add("@SNo",System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter Vendor_ID=cmd.Parameters.Add("@Vendor_ID",  
                                                                   System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,10);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUserName.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRegPassword.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_ConPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRegConPassword.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRegFName.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRegLName.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_Title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRegTitle.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_OtherEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtOtherEmail.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_PhoneNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =txtRegTelephone.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_MobileNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =txtRegMobile.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_FaxNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =txtRegFax.Text;
         cmd.Connection = SqlCon;
         try
         {
          Vendor_ID.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
          SqlCon.Open();
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          string VendorID = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string; 
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
           throw new Exception(ex.Message);
         }
         finally
         {
          string url = "../CompanyBasicInfo.aspx?Parameter=" + Server.UrlEncode(" + VendorID + ");
          SqlCon.Close();
         }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please format your code properly

Comment: You need to make it more readable it if you want people to help. Thats a lot of code to try an decipher and *then* help you.

Comment: pleae ask your question precisely

Comment: Why is `@Vendor_ID` specified as `OUTPUT` when you don't update the value in the proc?

Comment: @marc_s while true, that wouldn't explain a "too many arguments specified" - it would just mean the value isn't changed afterwards

Comment: I want the value of the "Vendor_ID" computed column after Insert so i mention it as OUTPUT in my SP. Still I get the same Error, please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your response.After i modify many times the C# code and SP according to your ideas, finally i got the answer for my question. I removed 'Vendor_ID' from my SP and add few codes in my code as shown below.

Stored procedure :

```
      ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_User_Info3]
      @SNo INT OUTPUT,
      @UserName VARCHAR(30),
      @User_Password VARCHAR(12),
      @User_ConPassword VARCHAR(12),
      @User_FirstName VARCHAR(25),
      @User_LastName VARCHAR(25),
      @User_Title VARCHAR(35),
      @User_OtherEmail VARCHAR(30),
      @User_PhoneNo VARCHAR(14),
      @User_MobileNo VARCHAR(14),
      @User_FaxNo VARCHAR(14)
      AS
      BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO User_Info3 (UserName,User_Password,User_ConPassword,User_FirstName,User_Title,User_OtherEmail,User_PhoneNo,User_MobileNo,User_FaxNo)
           VALUES (@UserName,@User_Password,@User_ConPassword,@User_FirstName,@User_LastName,@User_Title,@User_OtherEmail,@User_PhoneNo,@User_MobileNo,@User_FaxNo)
  SET @SNo = Scope_Identity() 
      END
```

C# Code :

```
    protected void BtnUserNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    SqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("usp_User_Info3", SqlCon);
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd2.CommandText = "usp_User_Info3";
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter SNo=cmd2.Parameters.Add("@SNo", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@User_Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRegPassword.Text.Trim();
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@User_ConPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRegConPassword.Text;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@User_FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRegFName.Text.Trim();
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@User_LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRegLName.Text.Trim();
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@User_Title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRegTitle.Text.Trim();
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@User_OtherEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtOtherEmail.Text.Trim();
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@User_PhoneNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRegCode1.Text;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@User_MobileNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRegCode2.Text;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@User_FaxNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRegCode3.Text;
    cmd2.Connection = SqlCon;
    try
    {
       SNo.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
       cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
       string VendorID = "VEN" + cmd2.Parameters["@SNo"].Value.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
    string url = "../CompanyBasicInfo.aspx?Parameter=" + Server.UrlEncode(" + VendorID + ");
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "callfunction", "alert('Login created successfully');window.location.href = '" + url + "';", true);
     SqlCon.Close();
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

- You're not setting the direction of the `@SNo` parameter
- You're calling the command twice - Just call it with `ExecuteScalar` if you want the return value.
- You're not setting the value of your `@Vendor_ID` output parameter in the stored procedure.

Comment: Re calling it twice: that is *true*, but it won't cause this error. Good spot, though. Re not setting direction, again: it will mean the updated value is not available afterwards, but it won't cause this error

Comment: @MarcGravell If it's an output parameter, won't that cause the mismatched of parameters?

Comment: *from memory*, no but I would be happy to be wrong - I suppose the OP could try making it InputOutput, though

Comment: @MarcGravell I was trying to avoid the conclusion that the entire thing was a complete crock... :)

Comment: See, the thing is: the error message is complaining about ***too many*** parameters, not *too few*

Comment: what i have to change in SP Mr.podilusa?

Comment: @Hari `SELECT @VendorID = Vendor_ID From User_Info3 WHERE SNo = @SNo`

Comment: I remove the 'OUTPUT' from SP for SNo because i don't want it value in my code.So direction is not need now.I remove the "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()" from code. how to set value for Vendor_ID ? Still I get the same error. Please anybody help me.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I would wager that `cmd` is being re-used and has parameters from a previous call left in it. One option would be to call `cmd.Parameters.Clear()`, but frankly I see little point re-using this `SqlCommand` instance - it would be better to use a new command each time:

```
using(var cmd = SqlCon.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "usp_User_Info3";
    // TODO: add parameters
    // TODO: call one of the Execute* methods
}
```

Comment: you can use the instructions in the below link to debug the stored procedure from visual studio                                             http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/debugging/debugging_otn.htm

Comment: @KishoreBorra was that meant to be directed to the OP?

Comment: sorry i meant to provide that info to Hari

Answer (score 0):

**User_OtherEmail** column doesnt exist in the table

**Correct Stored Procedure**

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_User_Info3]
     @SNo INT OUTPUT,
     @Vendor_ID VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT, 
     @UserName VARCHAR(30),
     @User_Password VARCHAR(12),
     @User_ConPassword VARCHAR(12),
     @User_FirstName VARCHAR(25),
     @User_LastName VARCHAR(25),
     @User_Title VARCHAR(35),
      @User_Email VARCHAR(30),
     @User_PhoneNo VARCHAR(14),
     @User_MobileNo VARCHAR(14),
     @User_FaxNo VARCHAR(14)
     AS
     BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
     INSERT INTO User_Info3 (UserName,User_Password,User_ConPassword,User_FirstName,     
     User_LastName,User_Title,User_Email,User_PhoneNo,User_MobileNo,User_FaxNo)
           VALUES  (@UserName,@User_Password,@User_ConPassword,@User_FirstName,@User_LastName,
           @User_Title,@User_Email,@User_PhoneNo,@User_MobileNo,@User_FaxNo)
    SET @SNo = Scope_Identity()
    SELECT Vendor_ID From User_Info3 WHERE SNo = @SNo
    END
```

and the **c# code to be modified accordingly** .

Comment: That would explain a *different* error message (about column not existing, or similar) - not sure it explains a message about too many parameters, though

Answer (score 0):

After all these answers from great minds I can't believe you are still stuck. Here are my suggestions

In your PROC

```
'maintain this in your parameter
@Vendor_ID VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT,
```

Update to Select `VendorID` into `@VendorID`. See the second line

```
    SET @SNo = Scope_Identity()
    SELECT @Vendor_ID=VendorID From User_Info3 WHERE SNo = @SNo
```

In C#, do not call `ExecuteScalar` use `ExecuteNonQuery`

```
string newVendorID = "";
try
{
      Vendor_ID.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
      SqlCon.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      if(Vendor_ID.Value != null)
          newVendorID = Vendor_ID.Value.ToString();
}
```

You could rename the `Vendor_ID` parameter to something more meaningful, like `VendorIDParam`. Hope this helps?